# how to show output before clicking the button like eventlistener of js in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, calculator, react-state

Here I want to show the output to users before clicking on the calculate button, but I don't know how to do it.

I think I have to use useEffect to print the output but I don't know-how.

I have removed calculateF() and calculateP() function from here because it increases the number of lines. To see the whole code visit the sandbox link.

please help.
[My code sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/pme-form-0vqv4?file=/demo.js)

```
export default function SimpleTooltips() {
  const [f, setF] = useState("");
  const [i, setI] = useState("");
  const [n, setN] = useState("");
  const [p, setP] = useState("");

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    switch (name) {
      case "f":
        setF(value);
        break;
      case "i":
        setI(value);
        break;
      case "n":
        setN(value);
        break;
      case "p":
        setP(value);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  const resetForm = () => {
    setF("");
    setI("");
    setN("");
    setP("");
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (f === "") {
      setF(calculateF(i, n, p));
    } else if (p === "") {
      setP(calculateP(i, n, f));
    }
  };

  return (
      <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <TextField
              type="number"
              variant="outlined"
              label="F"
              name="f"
              value={f}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              fullWidth
            />
            <TextField
              type="number"
              variant="outlined"
              label="i"
              name="i"
              value={i}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              fullWidth
              required
            />
            <TextField
              type="number"
              variant="outlined"
              label="N"
              name="n"
              value={n}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              fullWidth
              required
            />
            <TextField
              type="number"
              variant="outlined"
              label="P"
              name="p"
              value={p}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              fullWidth
            />
        <br />
            <Button variant="contained" fullWidth type="submit" color="primary">
              Calculate
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              fullWidth
              color="default"
              onClick={resetForm}
            >
              Clear
            </Button>
      </form>
  );
}
```

Thank you in adv

Answer (score 0):

You want to show the output without before user have clicked the button,  right?

One way of doing this would be to update your `handleChange` function. You can check if both the values are present in the state( checking with `if` is important else you will run into issue). If value are present then you can update the state corresponding to that field.

I would suggest use descriptive variable names, as to what `f` or `p` really are and use different states for different fields and not just one.

Comment: can you share the code sandbox link, it will be of great help. Thank you

Comment: Can you share, What is `f`, `p` and other variables and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is a simple calculator where I have to solve F = P (1+i)^N , I and N are required field which means user have to enter its value and F and P are optional where user have to enter anyone value to get other as output